# Install tightvnc in arch linux raspberry pi

Tags: linux, archlinux

How do I install the tightvnc in the Arch Linux os on Raspberry Pi?

Are the procedures and commands different?

Comment: Have you tried installing it?

Comment: i was able to install it on the debian wheezy, i haven't tried it on archlinux yet.

Comment: do i need to install the gui for the desktop first before i can install tightvnc?

Comment: "Different" from what?

Answer (score 2):

You ask 'if the procedures are different' but don't specify different from what? In the comments you clarify you have experience with Raspbian, you should update your question to be more specific.

[pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman) is the command you need. Here is how you search for software in Arch:

```
> pacman -Ss tigervnc
community/tigervnc 1.4.3-4
    Suite of VNC servers and clients. Based on the VNC 4 branch of TightVNC.
```

And you would install it like so:

```
> sudo pacman -S tigervnc
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that TightVNC isn't part of the official repositories any more. TigerVNC is a fork that is supported by the standard Arch Linux repositories.

`pacman -S tigervnc` as root should install it with all necessary dependencies.